# What material absorb IR and let visible light through?

Tags: visible-light, material-science, infrared-radiation, optical-materials

Beside water, what common materials -- man made or otherwise -- absorb infrared (~800nm-~1100nm) and let visible light through? I think glass IR stop filters absorb, but glass itself reflects IR. IR solar sheets for window tinting appear to reflect as well.

Comment: Renewal by Andersen windows.

Comment: Suppose you get 10 answers listing different materials with this property. How will you decide which is the "correct" one?

Comment: This appears to be a list-based question, which is generally considered off-topic as *too broad*. Please see the [help center](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) for details of what types of questions to avoid asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called Antimony doped Tin Oxide, nanocrystals with 10nm diameter. This lets 80% of visible light through, and absorbs 90% of IR.

> By incorporating smaller ATO nanocrystals synthesized by solvothermal synthesis, the IR shielding performance of the coating was greatly improved as compared to that using larger commercial ATO nanoparticles. The IR shielding coating with synthesized ATO nanocrystals can block more than 90% IR while it can maintain more than 80% transmittance at the visible range.

https://inis.iaea.org/search/search.aspx?orig_q=RN:50033630

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score -1):

Carbon dioxyde in the atmosphere. Also methane...

Answer (score -2):

I have heard that some plastics absorb IR rays and are transparent to visible light...